# Uniform convergence for particular values of $p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

The functions $f_n$ on $[0,1]$ are given by $$f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^p} \ \ (p >0).$$ 
For what values of $p$ does the sequence converge uniformly to its pointwise limit $f$?

Consider that \begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^p} &=& \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{1/n + nx^p} = 0.
\end{eqnarray*} We therefore have that $f_n \to 0$ pointwise. To determine what values of $p$ allow the sequence to converge such $f_n \to 0$ uniformly, we consider \begin{eqnarray*}
\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left| \frac{nx}{1+n^2x^p} \right| 
\end{eqnarray*}

From here I've started drawing the function for different values of $p$ and $n$, note that $p$ is not necessarily a prime. However, I have made no progress, I can't see a $p$ such that $f_n \not \to f$ uniformly.

Comment: $p \geq 1$ maybe?

Comment: The functions are differentiable, so you could compute their maxima for each value of $p$, setting the derivative to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f_n'(x)={n+(1-p)n^3x^{p}\over(1+n^2x^p)^2}
$$
For $p\le 1$, $f'>0$ i.e. $f$ attains its maximum at $x=1$ which is ${n\over1+n^2}$. As $\lim_n{n\over1+n^2}=0$, uniform convergence occurs. For $p>1$, $f'=0$ at $x=\left({1\over n^2(p-1)}\right)^{1\over p}$ at this point $f''<0$ and therefore $f$ attains maximum here which is 
$$
{1\over p}(p-1)^{1-{1\over p}}n^{1-{2\over p}}
$$
whose limit as $n\to\infty$ is
$$
\begin{cases}\infty,& p>2\\{1\over 2},& p=2\\0,&1<p<2\end{cases}
$$
So uniform convergence happens for $p\in(0,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show $f_n(x)\to0$ uniformly for $x\in E$ you need to prove 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in E}|f_n(x)|$$
(Note you wrote $\sum_{n>0}$ which is something else..)

In your case, note that we can differentiate $f_n(x)$ and then you can easily find the supremum/maximum.